# fwrite, but to string instead of file in C

Tags: c, string

I'm writing a C program to get a JPEG frame from a camera and do various stuff with it. I have the following function:

```
static void process_frame(const void *p, int size) {
        fwrite(p, size, 1, stdout);
}
```

It works great for writing the frame to stdout, but what I really need is something like this ("swrite" being like `fwrite`, but to a `char` instead of a file):

```
static char* process_frame(const void *p, int size) {
        char* jpegframe;
        swrite(p, size, 1, jpegframe);
        return jpegframe;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no swrite function (at least not that I could find).
So...

Are there any functions similiar to an "swrite" function?

or

How can I use the process_frame function with `printf` (and therefore `sprintf`) instead of `fwrite`?

Comment: What's wrong with malloc and memcpy?

Comment: You know `sprintf`? Although text-oriented functions have no parallel (AFAIK) with binary file operations. It's a use equivalent for `fprintf`.

Comment: `memcpy` or `memmove`, along with suitable allocation of destination buffers, would be the way to go here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the hood, it seems your pointer `p` is just a big array of bytes. You can cast it to a char array and use it:

```
char *jpegframe = (char *) p;
```

If you'd like to modify the frame, you might want to allocate some more memory and copy it in:

```
static char* process_frame(const void *p, int size) {
    char* jpegframe = malloc(size);
    memcpy(jpegframe, p, size);

    /* Do the processing... */

    return jpegframe;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

a `char` is just a single character. What you mean is a char buffer; and lo! your `p` is already one. Just use `(char*)p` (cast your void pointer to a char pointer), or `memcpy` the things that `p` points to to the char buffer of your choice.

Deamentiaemundi raises a good point: you probably pass `p` as `const void*` for a reason; if you plan to modify the data, you should memcpy the contents, definitely.

Comment: Casting a `const void *` to a non-const pointer can bite back. I think your  solution with `memcpy` is much better.